# Migrating from EJB2 to EJB3 EntityBean performance

Tags: performance, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, pool, ejb-2.x

Our project is designed in EJB 2.0.

We are not using any kind of EJB persistance methods in the BMP EntityBeans. In SessionBeans  we are getting reference to EntityHome object by using method getEJBXXXXHome() method and there by calling home.findByPrimaryKey("") method to get the EJB reference. Then we are calling actual methods for CRUD operations. In CRUD operations methods our people have used normal JDBC API methods.

Now we are migrating to EJB3. As part of migration from EJB 2.0 TO EJB3 am converting all my BMP EntityBeans to normal Java classes i.e there are no more entitybeans. If EJB container maintains a pool for the entitybeans earlier, it wont be there now. Its working normally when I have tested in my local machine for one transaction

My concern is, will it affects the perfromance for multiple threads in production?.

Afer changing the code now, every call creates one EntityBean Object. If 60k calls were made in just one hour will that affect my server. How this one is handled previously in EJB 2.0? is there any way to handle it in the changed code (i.e for normal java classes as they are no more entitybeans concept)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the overhead of objection creation/collection is going to be lower than the overhead of whatever the EJB container was doing for your entities previously.  I suspect a larger concern than object creation overhead is round-trips to the database.  Depending on your EJB container configuration, it's likely the container was optimizing the JDBC SQL and possibly caching the retrieved data (unrelated to object caching).  You should likely design your application to minimize calls to the database and ensure you don't execute unnecessary queries.

Ultimately, I suspect only you are going to be able to assess the performance of your application on your application server on your hardware.  I recommend following good programming practices to avoid egregious overhead, profile the result, and optimize from there rather than worrying about the performance up-front.

Comment: thank you for your response. I will profile before it is deployed in production. Shall i also consider creation of a custom pool for these java classes..i.e old entity beans? if yes, then can you suggest a best approach.

Comment: Pooling the state is less important than caching the data and remembering intelligently which objects need to be updated.  JPA was designed to do exactly this.  Is there a reason you're using JDBC SQL directly rather than JPA?

Comment: we have lot of native functionality written in JDBC SQL. converting them to JPA will be a big task. Hence we thought of removing the overhead of EJB2 in first sprint and then start migrating these to JPA in sprint2. I have one more query. I am making these old enitybeans(now plain java objects) to null after executing the method. Will that be sufficient for my performance query and also can u suggest good programming practices.